# Can a Mac mount a Debian install CD?

Tags: osx, iso

Working on OS X Yosemite (v10.11.5), I'm unable to mounst a Debian installer ISO (debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso on [Debian download page](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.5.0/amd64/iso-cd/)).  I get this error...

```
$ hdiutil mount debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso 
hdiutil: mount failed - no mountable file systems
```

As a work around, I can mount the CD in a Linux VM by following the "Create copy of image" steps in the [Debian installer docs](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso).

Is it possible to read the file contents on directly from a Mac, without the aid of a Linux VM?  Ultimately what I'm trying to do is write a script that can download the latest stable ISO, edit the ISO w/ pre-seeing data, and then perform an automated install of Debian on a VM.  This is mostly for learning purposes, but might useful down the road.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out.  It's a two step process.

**Step 1.  Attaching as a block device**

```
# the '-nomount' option avoids the 'mount failed' error
$ hdiutil attach -nomount debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso 
/dev/disk2              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk2s2            Apple_HFS   

# verify disk is a block device (indicated by 'b' at line start)
$ ls -l /dev/disk2
br--r-----  1 amorphid  staff    1,   5 Jul 27 19:41 /dev/disk2
```

**Step 1b. (Big Sur) Load the CD9660 kernel extension**

```
# Load the kext module
sudo kmutil load -p /System/Library/Extensions/cd9660.kext
```

**Step 2.  Mount the disk with cd9660 (aka ISO9660) file system**

```
# create mount point
$ mkdir -p /tmp/debian-installer

# mount the disk
$ mount -t cd9660 /dev/disk2 /tmp/debian-installer

# see da filez!
$ ls -l /tmp/debian-installer
total 2296
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    9468 Jun  4 09:24 README.html
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  185525 Jun  1 00:52 README.mirrors.html
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  100349 Jun  1 00:52 README.mirrors.txt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel     461 Jun  4 08:37 README.source
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    6000 Jun  4 09:24 README.txt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel     146 Jun  4 08:37 autorun.inf
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 boot
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 css
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       1 Jun  4 08:37 debian -> .
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 dists
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    4096 Jun  4 08:37 doc
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 efi
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 firmware
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  180335 Jun  2 03:18 g2ldr
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    8192 Jun  2 03:18 g2ldr.mbr
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 install
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 install.amd
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    4096 Jun  4 08:37 isolinux
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  275432 Jun  4 09:24 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    4096 Jun  4 08:37 pics
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 pool
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  368480 Jun  2 03:18 setup.exe
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 tools
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel     233 Jun  4 08:37 win32-loader.ini
```

**Step 3.  Unmount the disk**

```
# this will fail if the disk is being used
$ umount /dev/disk2
```

**Step 4.  Detach the disk**

```
$ hdiutil detach /dev/disk2
"disk2" unmounted.
"disk2" ejected.
```

Comment: A follow up question as I was not sure to start a new question. How do I unmount disks mounted using above method?

Comment: I have asked a new question regarding [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321876/how-to-unmount-a-disk-mounted-using-mount-and-not-hdiutil-or-diskutil)

Comment: @AnkitJain I added the steps above.  The commands are  `umount /dev/disk2` and `hdiutil detach /dev/disk2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the iso to a dmg first:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o debianConverted debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso
open debianConverted.dmg
diskutil list (to see your mount number)
hdiutil mount /dev/diskN (where N is the number for debianConverted)
```

Similar to what you would do to [create a bootable USB on macOS](https://blog.tinned-software.net/create-bootable-usb-stick-from-iso-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Hi.  I just ran `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o debianConverted debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso`, and then `hdiutil mount debianConverted.dmg `.  Still getting `hdiutil: mount failed - no mountable file systems`.

Comment: Double-click on the dmg (or 'open debianConverted.dmg'), then do a 'diskutil list' to see the mount points. Then you can do a 'htiutil mount /dev/disk3', or whatever your number is.

Comment: Double clicking (or using 'open') on the .dmg (or the .iso) would not successfully mount.  I did manage to find an answer though, which I posted in this thread.